# Arduino Serial.Available() is false after 255 bytes

Tags: c++, https, arduino, uart, arduino-c++

Im working with Arduino Nano BLE 33 connected to Dragino NB-IoT LTE Bg96. Im trying to read a the reply of a https get call. The get call was succes and to read it I send the AT Command to the BG96. It then send it to Uart, and im trying to read it on the arduino. But after 255 characters it stops, i tried it with different websites (which has different responses) but it breaks after 255 characters. I used uint8_t(for index) before, so i thought that was the mistake but it stills happen now after I change it to int.

Part of my function :

```
uint8_t bg96::check_response(char* desired_response){
char character;
int index = 0;
memset(response, 0, ARRAYSIZE);
while (Serial1.available()){
    character = Serial1.read();
    response[index] = character;
    index++;
    Serial.print(character);
}
response[index] = '\0';
Serial.print("index : ");
Serial.println(index);

Serial.print("Response:");
Serial.println(response);
```

Response :

```
+QHTTPGET: 0,200
AT+QHTTPREAD=80
CONNECT
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.14.2
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Request-Id: 616401ed-bb42-43b3-aba9-ab53952b9405
X-Token-Id: d242eb9a-9dc3index : 255
Response:
```

It should be:

[Complete HTTPS REsponse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmn3v.png)

Comment: Include the declaration of `response` and other relevant parts.

Comment: is it not just a gap between bytes which causes that available is 0 for a short moment but you stop reading?

Comment: I did a bit of research. I suspect that the value `__#define SERIAL_RX_BUFFER_SIZE` will be of interest to you. Just drop these trashy libraries and code the UART driver yourself. It ain't hard.

Comment: @Lundin, it is a nRF52840 with mbed OS

Comment: @Juraj So...? The rx buffers have a limit.

Comment: @Lundin, "code the UART driver yourself. It ain't hard." are you sure?

Comment: I've written at least twenty of them over the years, so yes I'm damn sure. You need to understand basic embedded systems, basic electronics and C programming. Unfortunately, Arduino will teach you neither of those prerequisites - it will just teach you to become a code primate who can only use pre-made libs without understanding how they work. That's why you should get rid of it sooner rather than later.

Comment: @Lundin, how do you make code portable for different MCU for fast prototyping?

Comment: @Juraj You can't make drivers portable, unless the very same hardware peripheral exists on a different MCU by the same manufacturer. You can make a HAL so that the application layer turns portable, but that's not a concern for prototypes.

Answer (score 0):

As the error occurs after a certain bytes, it would usually mean a overflow of some sort. You haven't shown complete code, what is the size of response array (or ARRAYSIZE, as you are clearing it with a memset). Most likely your response[index] results in an out of bounds access